# How do you inject a scoped service into an implementation of IClaimsTransformer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

ASP.Net core lets you modify a ClaimsPrincipal using an implementaion of IClaimsTransformer. I understand that you register it like this:

```
app.UseClaimsTransformation(o => o.Transformer = new MyClaimsTransformer());
```

But inside MyClaimsTransformer I need access to my database. My question is how can I inject or get access to a scoped service that provides that data access inside of MyClaimsTransformer?

Comment: What scope do you need? Request scope or a custom one?

Comment: @Dovydas Navickas I need Request scope because I want to grab a repository service that uses Entity Framework and I want to make sure it gets disposed when the request ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible at the moment.

Implementation of the method you're using can be found [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/ClaimsTransformationAppBuilderExtensions.cs#L38-L53)

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseClaimsTransformation(this IApplicationBuilder app, Func<ClaimsPrincipal, Task<ClaimsPrincipal>> transform)
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
    }
    if (transform == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(transform));
    }

    return app.UseClaimsTransformation(new ClaimsTransformationOptions 
    {
        Transformer = new ClaimsTransformer { OnTransform = transform }
    });
}
```

As you can see, it is a simple proxy method for providing [`ClaimsTransformationOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/ClaimsTransformationOptions.cs) only property `Transformer`.

And when you get only `ClaimsPrincipal`, you cannot reach request from it.

It might have been you, who submitted this issue, but if it was not, you can track it [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/718).

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if this was an oversight in the design or something I'm missing because it seems to me that without injection you can't do any meaningful claims transformations because you don't have access to your data.

Comment: Mind accepting the answer as it is a correct one for the time being. I will update it whenever there are changes.

Comment: It's hard to fathom by RC1 that no one thought about how this scenario would be handled. If there's no solution by the end of next week I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue linked to in the answer from @dovydas-navickas has now been resolved.

In ASP.NET Core 1.0-RC2 the interface [IClaimsTransformer](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/IClaimsTransformer.cs#L19) was updated to take a [ClaimsTransformationContext](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/ClaimsTransformationContext.cs) which provides a way of accessing the services via the HttpContext.

For instance, if you need access to the memory cache, it can be retrieved like this

```
public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
{
    IMemoryCache cache = context.Context.RequestServices.GetService<IMemoryCache>();

    // ... the rest of the implementation.
}
```